# How to repeat code on every page from the second one?

Tags: article

I want to repeat certain code block on every page on top starting from second page. This is assuming that header is defined.
There is a package that can detect the number of page?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just need a way to determine the current page number? Some answers to that is available https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11962/how-to-determine-current-page-number  If the answers there do not address your question, please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Finding out the page number is not that difficult, but requires either using `\label`s, or tapping into the shipout routine (through page styles or otherwise). Can you be a bit more specific about your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two pagestyles called, for example `first` and `main`. Then in your document do something along the lines:

```
\documentclass...
% define the first and main pagestyles, or use existing ones
%   ...
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
% some text (which might set its own page style)
\thispagestyle{first} % for the first page
% more text on the first page then \pagestyle{main} comes into effect on the following pages
```

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, but there is a way to define new pagestyles without overwriting `fancyhdr` pagestyles?

Comment: @benjujo Yes. `fancyhdr` lets you define as many pagestyles as you want. Please read the manual (`> texdoc fancyhdr`). It is up to you not to overwrite any predefined styles.